# Array of random numbers in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can you create an array of random numbers using the `RAND` or `RANDBETWEEN` functions?

I'm trying to simulate the average outcome of 10 rolls of a six sided die (for example) in one formula?

---

I have tried the following in the past, but it only creates one random number and repeats it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:A10)^0)*(INT(RAND()*6)+1))/10
```

Comment: What do you mean by average outcome? Throws are: 1, 2, 6, 6. The average would be 3.75 but the most frequent is 6. Which is it you want?

Comment: I'm looking for the average, which should tend to 3.5 - this is just an example. I'm more interested in the functionality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `RANDBETWEEN` function can deal with array inputs. So

```
=RANDBETWEEN(ROW(1:10)^0,6)
```

effectively creates:

```
=RANDBETWEEN({1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1},{6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6;6})
```

which returns an array of 10 different random numbers between 1 and 6. This could easily be changed to 100 (or however many) random numbers by changing `A1:A10` to `A1:A100`.

---

Therefore, a single formula for the average of 10 separate dice rolls could be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A1:A10)^0,6)/10
```

or the equivalent CSE formula

```
{=AVERAGE(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A1:A10)^0,6))}
```

Comment: Clever! I wasn't sure that this is even possible.

Comment: I wasn't aware that RANDBETWEEN accepts array inputs. It's going to be handy in a simulation that I am working on.

Comment: @eshwar, Yea, I didn't know that `RANDBETWEEN` could do that either. Great answer by CallumDA33.

Comment: If only `RANDBETWEEN()` used Mersenne Twister like `RAND()` does!

Answer (score 2):

Three possible solutions:

1) You can do a decent job simulating the average of 10 rolls in a single cell by using a normal approximation. In the target cell enter:

```
=ROUND(NORM.INV(RAND(),3.5,SQRT(35/(12*10))),1)
```

I left the 10 in explicitly to show what you would need to modify if you want to vary the number of rolls. The fact that 35 is 3.5 * 10 is a coincidence, the number 35 would stay there even with 100 rolls. If you vary from 10, you might want to tweak the rounding. For 10 the standard deviation of is roughly 0.54, putting 1 and 6 at around 4.6 standard deviations away from the mean of 3.5. On average the formula will give you a value outside the range 1-6 1 out of every 270,000 times. A histogram of dice averages for 10 rolls forms a fairly nice bell-shaped curve, so this approach is certainly reasonable, and might work for your purposes.

2) A VBA *sub* which fills selected cells with exact spreadsheet formulas, relieving you of the tedious need to count. If there is a requirement that the final spreadsheet is macro-free, this can still be used in the development stage:

```
Sub DiceAverageFormula()
    'places a formula in the selected cell (or cells)
    'which simulates the average of rolling a die n 10 times

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim form As String

    n = InputBox("How many times do you want to roll?", "Dice", 10)
    If n < 1 Then Exit Sub
    form = "=Average(Randbetween(1,6)"
    For i = 2 To n
        form = form & ",Randbetween(1,6)"
    Next i
    form = form & ")"
    Selection.Formula = form
End Sub
```

3) For completeness sake, The naïve VBA UDF:

```
Function RollDice(n As Long, Optional k As Long = 6) As Double
    'simulates the rolling of n k-sided die, returing the average

    Application.Volatile 'can be removed, of course

    Dim i As Long, sum As Long
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To n
            sum = sum + .RandBetween(1, k)
        Next i
    End With
     RollDice = sum / n
End Function
```

To test the various approaches, I filled 30 rows with each approach and made 5-number summaries of the results (which appear reasonable):

[image]

Needless to say, the fact that in *this* screenshot the mean for the normal approximation is lower than the other two is not particularly relevant. You would need a fairly large number of runs before a statistical test could detect any difference between the first column and the other 2.

**On Edit**: Here is a graph of exact probability vs. normal approximation for the mean of 10 rolls of a fair die. It underscores how reasonable it is to use the central limit theorem here. Even though n = 10 is a somewhat small sample size, the exact probability is sufficiently symmetric and unimodal that it already looks fairly normal:

[image]

Comment: I really like this answer - use of the normal distribution is fascinating! I found another alternative using worksheet functions, you might find it interesting

Answer (score 1):

The only direct answer to the question I can think of is to define a named range called (say) randeval and use the hidden EVALUATE function in its definition:-

```
 =EVALUATE(REPT("+RANDBETWEEN(1,6)",Sheet1!A1))
```

Enter 10 in A1, and the following in A2:-

```
=randeval/a1
```

Each time you hit Ctrl-Alt-F9, it will produce a new estimate of the average of ten dice rolls.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar in VBA, but Evaluate doesn't behave quite like Excel formulas:

```
a = [randbetween(row(1:10)^0,6)]                ' 3

b = [transpose(randbetween(row(1:10)^0,6))]     ' {3,3,6,4,6,4,2,5,1,2}

c = [average(randbetween(row(1:10)^0,6))]       ' 2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? It has one number of the dice in each row.
You input the number of "throws" in A1 and B column will show you the outcome.

```
In B1: 
=IF(A$1>=ROW(),RANDBETWEEN(1,6),"")
```

Then you just fill down to suit your need.

[image]

How about a UDF?

```
Function Throws(c)
    If Range(c).Value > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Range(c).Value
            Str1 = Str1 & "," & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
        Next i
        Throws = Mid(Str1, 2)
    End If

End Function
```

[image]

You enter the number of throws in any cell and use `=Throws("CELL")` to activate it.
And it returns the throws in one cell

EDIT2:

Not sure you can use average even with it being an array.

```
Function Throws(c) As Variant()
    Dim Str1 As Variant
    If Range(c).Value > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Range(c).Value
            If i = 1 Then Str1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
            Str1 = Str1 & "," & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
        Next i
        Throws = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(Str1))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: The specific problem is getting all of that into one formula - can you write an array formula that will return multiple different random numbers?

Comment: I'm not looking for a VBA solution although it is good to have it here for reference. Can you update your code to return an array of random numbers so that the average could be found using `AVERAGE` or similar?

Comment: @CallumDA33 Try it now.