# Random number assignment but assigning the same number for a particular group for a predetermined condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign random numbers to a group of items, but I want some of them to be assigned same number conditional on some common thing. As an example, consider a group of students of which the random number is going to be assigned. If I want female students get the same random and similarly male students get the same number. How could I achieve this? I have tried random function in excel and buch of if conditions, but couldn't achieve what I want. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried and where it went wrong?

Comment: put the random number in another spot, a variable in vba or a table in excel.  Then you can use vlookup to assign that number to the list using excel functions or loop and assign the value from the variable in vba.  But Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  please show what you have tried and where it went wrong.  As is this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

By far the easiest method is to have two random numbers in separate cells and refer to them by lookup function (also suggested by @Scott Craner)

The formula in cell `C2` is

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$3,2,0)
```

[image]

## Method 2

If you want to avoid using other cells you can create an array of different random numbers using the method in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40657050/2859347

For example, an array of two random numbers between 1 and 10 looks like this:

```
{=RANDBETWEEN(ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0,ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0*10)}
```

The two different random numbers need to  be matched to `M` and `F` so you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH`

My setup looks like this:
[image]

And to get the random numbers you need to highlight `C2:C8`, press `F2` and enter the following into cell `C2`:

```
=INDEX(RANDBETWEEN(ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0,ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0*10),MATCH(B2:B8,{"M","F"},0))
```

Enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. When done correctly, you will see curly brackets surround the formula.

```
{=INDEX(RANDBETWEEN(ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0,ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0*10),MATCH(B2:B8,{"M","F"},0))}}
```

---

**Note** if you want to get a random number similar to the `RAND` function you can do something like `RANDBETWEEN(1,100000)/100000`

```
=INDEX(RANDBETWEEN(ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0,ROW($A$1:$A$2)^0*100000)/100000,MATCH(B2:B8,{"M","F"},0))
```

Answer (score 0):

With names in column **A** and sex in column **B**, in both **E1** and **E2** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="F",$E$1,$E$2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

*This is only a sample to demo how to get the same random to repeat.*